# наклонения в языках мира

Tags: наклонение

Как вы знаете, в русском языке три наклонения: изъявительное, побудительное и сослагательное.

Я еще читала о "сомневательном", "пересказывательном" и "вычислительном" в других языках. Известны ли вам языки, в которых нет **сослагательного наклонения**?

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, можно вспомнить лишь уникальную попытку исследователя языка одного из малых бразильских племён - доказать отсутствие в том языке вложенных конструкций (был док. фильм об этом). Косвенно это отрицает и сослагательное наклонение. Ему удалось это обосновать в ограниченном кругу исследователей (общим языковым концепциям это противоречит). А без повелительного наклонения (выраженного своим для конкретного языка средством, напр. модальной частицей, вариантом обращения или хотя бы интонацией) трудно представить себе возможность общения на таком языке.

Comment: ... большое спасибо, Александр! вижу, что неправильно сформулировала свой вопрос... сейчас буду исправлять... : )

Answer (score 0):

Грамматические системы языков мира сходны. Сослагательное наклонение должно быть во всех языках. Правда, иногда эти понятия в разных языках называются по-разному, но сути это не меняет, что-то всё равно должно выражать сослагательное значение.

Comment: Потрясающее заявление. Следующим должно быть, наверное,  утверждение, что русский язык самый древний в мире и от него пошла грамматика всех языков.

Comment: А аргументированный ответ можно? Интересно, как японец скажет «Я хотел бы пойти погулять»? Вот вам контраргумент на ваш ответ: http://krakozyabr.ru/2010/10/naklonenie-glagola-v-yaponskom-yazyke/, http://jeffkr.narod.ru/korean_munjang.html. По запросу «вьетнамский язык сослагательное наклонение» почему-то ничего не нашлось, однако и там тоже есть, предполагаю.

Comment: Я не знаю японского, но в принципе представляю. В японском  масса всякого рода внеграмматических средств для выражения мысли.  Некоторые из них передают то, что русский, возможно, сочтет наклонением. Рассказывать о них  лучше специалисту, а вам могу предложить подумать о более простой задачке. Как в русском языке выразить будущее время без "буду"? Как выразить повелительное наклонение прошедшим временем? ("затра я иду в кино", "первый пошел!" и проч.)

Comment: http://krakozyabr.ru/2010/10/uslovnoe-naklonenie/ - если это сослагательное наклонение, то я балерина. "Формы условного наклонения в японском языке принимает не только глагол, но и другие спрягаемые слова: прилагательные, связки". Вы можете себе представить **спрягаемое прилагательное** в русском? Я думаю, вас смутило то, что передача условия через контекстные суффиксы здесь названо "сослагательным наклонением". Никак не могу признать это именно грамматической конструкцией.

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить именно о специальной грамматической конструкции, по функционалу подобной сослагательному русского,  то подобного нет в китайском, в японском, кажется, в корейском, вьетнамском... В арахаичных языках аборигенов Океании, вроде бы нет (там вообще модальность не развита), тоже - в индейских... 
Подробности - гугл в помощь, я не специалист.